# fixing rotation speed with LIBGDX

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx

I'm trying some functions with java & libgdx.

I've spent maybe 1 hour on this and I can't figure out why the rotation is 2 time faster clockwise than anticlockwise.

If you see something I missed, please help me. Thank you all !

```
game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(fond, 0, 0);
    game.batch.draw(ts, ts.getX(), ts.getY(), ts.getWidth()/2, ts.getHeight()/2, ts.getWidth(), ts.getHeight(), 1, 1, rot);
    game.batch.end();

    if(rot < 1 ) {
        hor = Rot.ACLOCKW;
        last_changeA = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - last_changeC);
    }
    if(rot > 359) {
        hor = Rot.CLOCKW;
        last_changeC = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - last_changeA);
    }

    switch(hor) {

    case CLOCKW :
        rot -= 100*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
        break;

    case ACLOCKW : 
        rot += 100*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); 
    }              
}
```

Comment: I tried to say "Hello everyone" at the beginning of the post but it didn't want me to add it, so I add it here :).